# Why do I not server calls go out in google developer tools when code is inserted into Iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I'm a beginner when it comes to coding and web development.

If a client is using google tag manager to fire a script inside a Iframe how come it does not show in the Network tab in google developer tools?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Because it's all packaged in gtm.js, which fires almost at the beginning. Go ahead an inspect that mess of JavaScript, I'm sure you will find the script that fired lurking in there.